# Trying to prove that $\left|z-(z^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right| < 1$ for $Re(z)>0$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $$\left|z-(z^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right| < 1$$ for $Re(z)>0$, but struggling to do so.  Any thoughts on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $ z - \sqrt{z^2+1} = \frac{1 }{  z + \sqrt{z^2 + 1}} $.

Why is the norm of the denominator greater than 1?

Comment: OK, I can see intuitively why this is the case.  In trying to prove it algebraically Ive got as far as |z+(z^2+1)^0.5|^2 >= 1 + 2(Re(z)Re((z^2)^0.5) + 2(Im(z)Im((z^2+1)^0.5), so if I can show the last two terms are >=0 then I'm there.  Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Got there - the final two terms above = 2 Re(z*(1+z^2)^0.5)  (where z* here is z conjugate).  By considering the 2 cases for Re(z)>0 with 1) z in quadrant 1 and 2) z in quadrant 4, one can show Re(z*(1+z^2)^0.5)>=0, hence the result.